# Algorithm for rope burning

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Generalized from a technical interview question:

> Original question: There are two ropes, each rope takes 1 hour to
>   burn. But either rope has different densities at different points, so
>   there’s no guarantee of consistency in the time it takes different
>   sections within the rope to burn.
>
> How do you use these two ropes to measure 45 minutes?

I have a generalized version:

> There are n ropes, each rope takes x minutes to
>   burn (for simplicity assume x is positive integer). But the ropes have different densities at different points, so
>   there’s no guarantee of consistency in the time it takes different
>   sections within the ropes to burn.
>
> Using these n ropes, what time quantity can you measure?
>
> For example, with n = 1 and x = 60, I can measure 60 minute period
>   (burning one end of the rope), or 30 minute period (burning both ends
>   of the rope at the same time)

Of course my aim would be finding an algorithm with minimal complexity. I imagine the solution to this would involve dynamic programming, but I am not quite sure. My brute force solution is as followed:

1. Start at minute 0, we have n ropes, each takes x minutes to burn. For a given rope, we have choices either to burn both ends, one end, or not burning the rope at all. Let number of ropes that will not be burnt at this stage be x, number of ropes that will be burnt one end be y, and number of ropes that will not be burnt at all be z. We have x + y + z = n and that x,y,z are positive integers and z != 0. Consider all possible cases for x, y and z and add those cases to a stack/queue.
2. For each item in the stack/queue, determine how many minutes have passed when there is a rope finishes burning. Output the time that has passed (calculated based on how long the finished rope has burnt, and which ends were burnt at what time). Now we have another scenarios with certain amount of ropes that are being burnt. Repeat the step 1 argument with x + y + z = n - 1 (with constraints imposed on x, y, and z since some ropes are still burning and we cannot set the fire off) and add all the newly generated cases to the stack/queue.
3. Repeat 2. until n = 0 (All ropes finished burning)

Edit:
For n = 2 and x = 60, I've found that the following time period can be measured: 30, 60, 90, 120, 45 and 15.

As suggested, I posted the question on cs.stackexchange.com: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32455/algorithm-for-rope-burning-problem

Comment: http://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/teaser.php?id=673&op=2&comm=1#c

Comment: Great question! Would you be able to post sample cases for n=1, 2, 3 and x = 60? I have found by hand 1=30, 60_____________________2=30, 60, 90, 120, 15, 45_____________________3=30, 60, 90, 120, 15, 45, 150, 180, 7.5, 22.5. I just want to make sure I am thinking about this correctly before I try to tackle the problem.

Comment: A really interesting problem, but it probably belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: StackOverflow is for actual problems you're experiencing with your code. It's not about theoretical discussions or interview questions. This would appear to be more suitable for a different [se] site such as [computerscience.se].

Comment: @user2570465: How do you get 15 with 2 ropes?

Comment: @Ben Voigt At t=0, we burn rope 1 from both ends and rope 2 from 1 end. At t=30, rope 1 has completely burned, and rope 2 is half burned with 30 minutes left. At this point, we light the other half of rope 2. Thus, at t=45, the final half of rope 2 has completely burned.

Comment: @user2570465: Right, that got you 45 (answers the original form of the problem).  But you said you can get 15.

Comment: you can start your timer at t=30.

Comment: @user2570465: I don't think that really works, not unless you can quench burning ropes.  I mean, yes, you could choose to boil water for 15 minutes, given an extra 30 minutes prep time.  But you couldn't measure 15 minutes after an event *outside* your control, no matter how much prep time you have, unless you can quench a partly burnt rope.

Comment: @Ben Voigt. At t=30, the first rope has completely burned, so you know you can start measuring time then. Conveniently, there is 30 min left of the second rope left at that time, so you light the second end of that one on fire. And the final half should burn in 15 minutes. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt in order to measure 15 minutes fold the rope from middle and then burn from both sides. :)

Comment: @VikramBhat: Nope, that's the same as folding the rope, cutting it in two, and thinking you have two 30 minute ropes.  But the question says the density is not uniform.

Comment: @user2570465: There is an evil secret agent watching the exit of your building.  You can see him but he can't see you or your ropes, as long as you stay inside.  I tell you to leave 15 minutes after he does.  Can you do it?  Assume he is going to continue watching you for between 4 and 6 more hours before leaving; you have plenty of time for burning ropes partway.  But he leaves when he wants, not when you want him to.

Comment: @user2570465: For n = 2 and x = 60, I believe you got the right answers.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: No, I cannot do that. That is a different problem. The problem here asks what time intervals can you measure? There are no constraints on how long it takes you to measure that time interval. I just have to say Event 1 was the start, Event 2 was the end, and the difference between the time at which Event 2 and Event 1 occurred was 15 minutes. With your evil secret agent problem, you are putting an additional constraint. You are saying that you get to specify Event 1 as the time when the evil secret agent leaves and I have to find Event 2.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my attempt to solve the problem with greater efficiency. I might have overlooked something, so be wary even if it seems to make sense.

We can start with a base state of 1 rope yields x minutes or x/2 minutes. Now, suppose it is possible to measure `x_prev` minutes with `n` ropes. Then, consider what happens if we add the `n+1`th rope. We can

1. Wait for the whole `x_prev` minutes to expire, then burn the next rope from 1 end. This means we can achieve `x_prev + x` minutes.
2. Wait for the whole `x_prev` minutes to expire, then burn the next rope from 2 ends. This means we can achieve `x_prev + x/2` minutes.
3. Start burning the `x_prev` minutes as we burn the next rope from 1 end. This means we can achieve `abs( x - x_prev )` minutes.
4. Start burning the `x_prev` minutes as we burn the next rope from 2 ends. This means we can achieve `abs( x/2 - x_prev)` minutes.

We do not care about a time `t` that was achieved with `m` with `m<=n-1` ropes because we would have considered these four cases when we were adding the `m+1-th` rope.

These seem like the only four cases. So, in pseudocode, perhaps something like this

```
let solutions be a list of measurable times
def solve( n , x ):
    if n <= 0
         return, you cannot measure any times
    else
         #set up base case n=1
         append x/2 and x to solutions

         #we can be efficient by only checking the times achievable with n-1 ropes
         #we will store the index of the first time that was recorded with n-1 ropes
         #in start_idx
         let start_idx be an index in the solutions array

         #assume the array indices start at 0. then start_idx is the index
         #of the first recorded time measurable with 1 rope.
         start_idx = 0

         #then continuously add additional ropes until we have n ropes
         for i in 2..n

              let solutions_to_add be a list

              for j in start_idx..solutions.size() - 1
                   if solutions does not contain time+x
                        append time+x to solutions_to_add
                   if solutions does not contain time+x/2
                        append time+x/2 to solutions_to_add
                   if solutions does not contain abs( x-time )
                        append abs( x-time ) to solutions_to_add
                   if solutions does not contain abs( x/2-time )
                        append abs( x/2-time ) to solutions_to_add

              #update the start_idx to be the starting index of times achievable with
              #i ropes
              start_idx = solutions.size()

              #then add the achievable times with i ropes
              for each time in solutions_to_add
                   append time to solutions
```

You can probably get O(1) run time for `solution contains` by using a boolean array for lookup. The overall algorithm seems to be O(n^2).

Is it correct? I'm not really sure if my four cases cover everything. I am pretty sure the induction-like process is correct.